# Angular - How to display boolean value for edit in checkbox

Tags: angular

In my Angular-14 project I have this interface:

```
export interface IStudentUpdate {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  userName: string;
  email: string;
  mobileNumber: string;
  isAdmin: boolean;
}
```

Then this is the component:

component.ts:

```
  editStudent() {
    this.editStudentForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(25), Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z \-\']+')]],
      lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(25), Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z \-\']+')]],
      userName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(50), UsernameValidator.cannotContainSpace]],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$')]],
      mobileNumber: ['', [Validators.maxLength(15)]],
      isAdmin: ['']
    });
  }

  editStudentData(templateDetail: TemplateRef<any>, row: any) {
   this.studentList = row
   this.editStudentForm.controls['firstName'].setValue(row.firstName);
   this.editStudentForm.controls['lastName'].setValue(row.lastName);
   this.editStudentForm.controls['userName'].setValue(row.userName);
   this.editStudentForm.controls['email'].setValue(row.email);
   this.editStudentForm.controls['mobileNumber'].setValue(row.mobileNumber);
   this.editStudentForm.controls['isAdmin'].setValue(row.isAdmin.value);
   this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(templateDetail, Object.assign({}, { class: 'gray modal-lg' }));
  }
```

Finally the component.html:

```
<ng-template #studentEdit>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">{{ pageLabel }}</h4>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="onClose()">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="visually-hidden">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="add-form" [formGroup]="editStudentForm" (ngSubmit)="onEditStudentSubmitForm()">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="firstName">First Name<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='firstName' id="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lastName">Last Name<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='lastName' id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="userName">User Name<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='userName' id="username" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Email">Email<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName='email' id="studentEmail" placeholder="example@email.com">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="mobileNumber">Mobile Number</label>
              <ngx-intl-tel-input
                [cssClass]="'form-control mb-3'"
                [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries"
                [enableAutoCountrySelect]="false"
                [enablePlaceholder]="true"
                [searchCountryFlag]="true"
                [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2, SearchCountryField.Name]"
                [selectFirstCountry]="false"
                [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.Nigeria"
                [phoneValidation]="true"
                [separateDialCode]="true"
                name="mobileNumber" formControlName="mobileNumber">
              </ngx-intl-tel-input>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"><br><br>
                <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="isAdmin">
                <label for="isAdmin" class="custom-control-label">Is Admin</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="cancelCreate" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="onClose()">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="isLoading" (click)="editValidate()"><span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
          <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save Changes</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

When I loaded the form for display the values so I can edit the data, every other control was okay apart from isAdmin (a boolean).

It suppose to check the checkbox on true, but nothing is happening.

How do I get this corrected?

Thanks

Comment: If `isAdmin` boolean, why do you set empty string as initial value?
Can you show what data comes in `row`?

Comment: @Eugene - the data that comes in the row is either true or false

Comment: Oh, you forgot set `formControlName="isAdmin"` in `input`

Comment: BTW you can use [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#setvalue) or [patchValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchvalue) to give value to the whole FormGroup at time